# plotly events not triggering

Tags: angular, plotly

I have a plotly chart in angular and it show's up fine but no events that I tried so far are fire-ing

**HTML:**

```html
                <plotly-plot [data]="chartData.data" 
                [layout]="chartData.layout"
                (selected)="onChartPointSelect($event)"
                (selecting)="onChartSelecting($event)"
                (plotly_click)="onChartPointSelect($event)"></plotly-plot>
```

**chartData:**

[image]

**TS:**

```js
onChartSelecting(data:any){
  console.log('onChartSelecting',data);    
}
onChartPointSelect(data:any){
  console.log('onChartPointSelect',data);
}
```

None of the clicks are happening if I click the marker on the chart.

I would basically like to click on a datapoint and get its content (relevant data)

```
"angular-plotly.js": "^1.0.1",
"plotly.js": "^1.44.1",
```

According to [this](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/issues/21#issuecomment-458220161) it should work

Answer (score 0):

At least in the code you posted here, you're actually not calling `onChartSelecting` (`(selecting)="onChartSelecting"` <-- missing `($event)`)

```
<plotly-plot [data]="chartData.data" 
             [layout]="chartData.layout"
             (selected)="onChartPointSelect($event)"
             (selecting)="onChartSelecting($event)"
             (plotly_click)="onChartPointSelect($event)"></plotly-plot>
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting a typo, but it is still not working, still same result like the events are not bound